# Trigger test class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am writing a test class for my trigger that checks for account duplicates.
But I get the following error in my test class :

> Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, String at line 35 column 42

The test class is:

```
@isTest

public class trg_AccountDuplicatePreventer_FinalTest{
    static testMethod void Test0_TestInsertWithValue()
    {

        //Set<Account> Accset = new Set<Account>();

        Account acc1 =  new Account(Name = 'Agency0', Phone='9811309977',Physical_Street__c = 'ABC0', Physical_State_Province__c = 'NY',Physical_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '2010',Physical_Country__c= 'USA');
        Account acc2 =  new Account(Name = 'Agency00', Phone='9811309988',Physical_Street__c = 'ABC00', Physical_State_Province__c = 'NY',Physical_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '2010',Physical_Country__c= 'USA');
        Account acc3 =  new Account(Name = 'Agency000', Phone='9811309999',Physical_Street__c = 'ABC000', Physical_State_Province__c = 'NY',Physical_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '2010',Physical_Country__c= 'USA');

        Account[] accs = new Account[]{acc1,acc2,acc3};
        insert accs;

        acc2.Phone='9811309999';
        acc3.Physical_Street__c='ABC0000';
        acc3.Phone='9811308888';
        update accs;

        Account dupe1 =  new Account(Name = 'Agency0', Phone='9811309977',Physical_Street__c = 'ABC0', Physical_State_Province__c = 'NY',Physical_Zip_Postal_Code__c =    '2010',Physical_Country__c= 'USA');


        try{
            insert dupe1;
            System.assert(false);
        }catch(DMLException e)
        {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++)
            {
                 System.assert(e.getNumDml() == 1);
                 System.assert(e.getDmlIndex(i) == 0);
                 System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i).size() == 3);
                 System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[0] == 'Name');
                 System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[1] == 'Phone');
                 System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[2] == 'Physical_Street__c');
                 System.assert(e.getDmlMessage(i).indexOf('An account with this name, phone, street already exists.') > -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error in my test code?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to specify more details like what you're trying to achieve here. Also, can you highlight the line where it fails.

Comment: Hi Anup, my trigger code tries to identify account duplicates in the system based on Account Name, Street & Phone matching or Name & Phone matching or Name & Street matching. The test class that I have written is giving me 100% coverage, but I am getting 1 test failure:

Comment: Message:System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, <BR/>Agency record with this Name/Phone/Physical Street exists in the system. If you wish to create agency record, change field value of "Create New Record" to YES.<BR/><BR/> Potential Duplicate Agencies Include:<BR/>Agencies with Name, Phone & Physical Street match: <a href=https://cs14.salesforce.com/001c0000003ncYmAAI>Agency000</a> | <BR/>Agencies with Name & Phone match: <a href=https://cs14.salesforce.com/001c0000003ncYmAAI>Agency000</a>

Comment: Stack Trace: Class.trg_AccountDuplicatePreventer_FinalTest.Test0_TestInsertWithValue: line 14, column 1

Answer (score 2):

getDmlFields returns a list of Schema.sObjectField objects so you would need to either compare them to other Schema.sObjectFields or get their name to compare them to a string.

```
System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[0] == Account.Name);
System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[1] == Account.Phone);
System.assert(e.getDmlFields(i)[2] == Account.Physical_Street__c);
```

Comment: i am getting the error the method signature is incorrect if I use the above.

Comment: I forgot that you can only get the name from a field describe result not a schema.field. I have fixed the code in the answer.